# obtaining values from a vector

Tags: c++

my code gets an error after inputting a string. i needed to have a string input (eg. add fruit) which will be put inside my vector by the "add" keyword. But when i also input a single word (eg. print) ,to print the elements in my vector. it wont work. any insights?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


vector <string> separate(string str){
   string word = "";
   vector <string> v = {0,0};
   for (auto x : str)
   {
       if (x == ' ')
       {
           v[1] = word;
           word = "";
       }
       else
       {
           word = word + x;
       }
   }
    v[0] = word;
    return v;

}

int main(){


    string user_input, command, item;
    int cmds;
    vector <string> result;



    while (1){
        cout << "Enter a command: ";
        getline(cin, user_input);

        vector <string> arrcmd = separate(user_input);
        (arrcmd.size() == 1) ? (command = arrcmd[0]) : (command = arrcmd[1], item = arrcmd[0]);
        cout << arrcmd.size() << endl;

 /*       command = arrcmd[0], item = arrcmd[1];   */
        cout << command << " " << item << endl;
```

Comment: `(command = arrcmd[1], item = arrcmd[0])` You know what the comma operator does, do you?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question as required please. This includes the exact error message, given input and expected output. As is your question isn't acceptable here.

Comment: `separate` always returns a vector of size 2, never a vector of size 1.

Comment: `(arrcmd.size() == 1) ? (command = arrcmd[0]) : (command = arrcmd[1], item = arrcmd[0]);` Don't abuse the ternary operator like this. It just makes the code harder to read and more error prone. Use an if statement when you're supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

`vector <string> v = {0,0};` creates a vector with two elements. Therefore, `separate` always returns a vector of size 2 - it just doesn't always populate its second element.

`main` attempts to make decisions based on the vector size - but the `size() == 1` path is never taken.